# Looping through nested array in Laravel Blade template

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-5

I have the following code :

```
@foreach($data['daily'] as $date => $dailyData)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$date}}</td>
        @foreach($dailyData as $key => $value)
            <td>
                <span>{{$value}}</span>
                <strong>{{$data['another_index'][$date][$key]}}</strong>
            </td>
        @endforeach
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

This is returning me an error

```
[ErrorException]
Undefined index: date
```

When the code is executed. Actually I have values there in `another_index` and I am able to print it.

Thanks in advance for the help.

```
[another_index] => Array
        (
            [2016-03-15] => Array
                (
                    [key] => 100.00%
                    [key1] => 0.00%
                    [key2] => 0.00%
                )

            [2016-03-14] => Array
                (
                    [key] => 10.00%
                    [key1] => 20.00%
                    [key2] => 30.00%
                )
```

Comment: You should post your `dd($data['daily'])` sample here or something like this.

Comment: dd($data['another_index']) as well so the existence of the $date index can be verified.

Comment: Have added the another_index data. I don't know why it is telling 'date' index is not found as if it is not taking the variable value.

Comment: You should loop another_index again .

Comment: I don't think so as I am directly calling for the value.

Comment: print $date right before your second foreach loop and verify that the date actually exists in $data['another_index']

Comment: I would highly recommend having your model put this data in a much easier to use format before passing it to the view. Your view has enough work to do generating HTML, the model should make that as simple as possible.

Comment: is "another_index" "daily" ? If you don't know what the key is why don't you just have it as ($data[] as $date => $dailyData) ?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your sample array this should give you what you're trying to achive:

```
@foreach($data as $date => $dailyData)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$date}}</td>
        @foreach($dailyData as $key => $value)
            <td>
                <span>{{$key}}</span>
                <strong>{{$value}}</strong>
            </td>
        @endforeach
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: This is not the data I wanted.  I have data there in $data['daily'] and $data['another_index'] as $data is a multi dimensional array.

Comment: Can you post your multildimensional array?